# Implement multiline skinny arrow syntax in sweetjs

Tags: javascript, preprocessor, sweet.js

I'm playing around with sweetjs and for the life of me can't figure out why [this rule for parameterless multiline skinny arrow syntax](http://sweetjs.org/browser/editor.html#macro%20-%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20rule%20infix%20%7B%20%28%29%20%7C%20%7B%20%24body%20...%20%24last%3aexpr%20%7D%20%7D%20=%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20function%28%20%29%20%7B%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%24body%20...;%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20%24last%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Avar%20fn%20=%20%28%29%20-%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20var%20a%20=%201;%0A%20%20a%20+%202;%0A%7D;%0Aexpect%28fn%28%29%29.to.equal%283%29;%0A) isn't matched

Code:

```
macro -> {
  rule infix { () | { $body ... $last:expr } } => {
    function( ) { 
      $body ...;
      return $last
    }
  }
}

var fn = () -> {
  var a = 1;
  a + 2;
};
expect(fn()).to.equal(3);
```

results in

```
SyntaxError: [macro] Macro `-` could not be matched with `> {} ; expect ()...`
10: var fn = () -> {
                ^
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try removing the semi-colon on the last line of the closure, for some reason the sweetjs compiler has trouble with $last and semi-colons.

```
macro -> {
 rule infix { () | { $body ... $last:expr } } => {
    function() {
      $($body) ...
      return $last
    }
  }
}

var fn = () -> {
  var a = 1
  a + 2
};
```

Comment: The reason the compiler has trouble with $last and `;` is because `;` isn't part of an expression. So the pattern will match up to `a + 2` but there will still be a token left. You can handle this by having two rules, one that matches without the `;` at the end and one with a `;`.